# Run onclick event only if Input was entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a submit button which, once clicked on, will run a function I have made: disable() but I want to make it so it only runs the onclick event if the input above had text.

```
    <form id="name">
        <p7>Please enter a name for your plan: </p7> <input required>
        <input type="submit" onclick="disable()">
    </form>
```

So if the user typed the required input after the  tags, and clicked on submit, it will run disable)
But if the user just clicks on submit without typing anything in the required input, disable() doesn't run

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your event check the length of the input. if it is more than zero disable the button otherwise don't disable it.

Comment: made that `.length` check inside the `disable()` function, something like:  `if (length == 0) return;` where length is the length of the `input.value`

Comment: function disable() {
                if (input.length != 0){
                    $("#table").addClass("disabledbutton");
                    document.getElementById('table_policy').style.display ='block';
                }
            }
Something like this? @CalvinNunes

Comment: almost, some answers below addresses my comment and work as you expect, check them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're want to use HTML5 validation, don't use click event of the button, use submit event of the form, as follows:

```js
function disable(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // Not needed, but for the snippet, for the form win't disappear
  console.log('Inside disable().');
}

$('#name').submit(disable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="name">
  <p7>Please enter a name for your plan: </p7> <input id="input" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I you want to validate it inside JS, use code like the following, that determinates if there is a value inside the input field:

```js
function disable() {
  if (!$('#input').val()) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('Inside disable().');
}

$('#button').click(disable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="name">
  <p7>Please enter a name for your plan: </p7> <input id="input" required>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can validate the input value at the beginning of the `disable` function, like so:

```js
function disable() {
    var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (!myInput.value.length) {
        alert('empty');
        return;
    }

    alert('fine');
}
```

```html
<form id="name">
    <p7>Please enter a name for your plan: </p7>
    <input required id="myInput">
    <input type="submit" onclick="disable()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable the button itself as you don't need it when there is no input present.
You need to add disable function on input box field.

Added **onkeyup** event on inputbox to track changes.

```js
disable()
function disable(){
  if($("#input").val()!=""){
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", false);
    //your own code here!! 
  }
  else{
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true);
    return;  //do nothing and return back.
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="name">
      <p7>Please enter a name for your plan: </p7> 
      <input onkeyup="disable()" value="" id="input" required>
      <input onclick="disable()" id="submit" type="submit">   
</form>
```